# Should I mock IO or not?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, exception

Say I have a simple file based database `Monad`. I would define it as shown below.

```
newtype MyDbFileBased a = MyDbFileBased {
        unMyDbDbFileBased :: ExceptT MyDbFileBasedError (ReaderT MyDbFileBasedEnv IO) a
    } deriving (
        Functor
    ,   Applicative
    ,   Monad
    ,   MonadError MyDbFileBasedError
    ,   MonadReader MyDbFileBasedEnv
    ,   MonadIO
    )
```

I have read that the above pattern (will post a link to the blog when I find it) is not recommended and that I should replace `IO` with a generic `Monad` like so.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

newtype MyDbFileBased m a = MyDbFileBased {
        unMyDbFileBased :: ExceptT MyDbFileBasedError (ReaderT MyDbFileBasedEnv m) a
    } deriving (
        Functor
    ,   Applicative
    ,   Monad
    ,   MonadError MyDbFileBasedError
    ,   MonadReader MyDbFileBasedEnv
    )

class Monad m => MonadFileBasedIO m where 
    readBytes :: FilePath -> m B.ByteString 
    writeBytes :: FilePath -> B.ByteString -> m () 
    ...

instance MonadFileBasedIO IO where 
    readBytes = B.readFile
    writeBytes = B.writeFile
```

This will supposedly make unit testing easier. The advise is to mock IO in testing with something like as follows.

```
data MockFS = EmptyDir
            | SingleFile FilePath String 
            deriving (Show)

newtype MockFileBasedIO a = MockFileBasedIO {
        unMockFileBasedIO :: State MockFS a
    } deriving (
        Functor
    ,   Applicative
    ,   Monad 
    ,   MonadState MockFS
    )

instance MonadFileBasedIO MockFileBasedIO where 
    readBytes pathReq = do
        dir <- get
        case dir of 
            EmptyDir                 -> fail "file not found"
            SingleFile path contents -> if pathReq == path 
                                            then pure (BU.fromString contents) 
                                            else fail "file not found"

    writeBytes path = put . SingleFile path . BU.toString
```

All this looks good to me until now. But then I want to add things like `catch` and `liftIO` to functions within `MyDbFileBased` type. I thought of adding `catchMonadFileBasedIO` and `liftMonadFileBasedIO` functions to `MonadFileBasedIO` typeclass and set `catchMonadFileBasedIO = catch` and `liftMonadFileBasedIO = liftIO` for `IO` monad. But then it brings in dependency on `MonadIO` and `Exception` typeclasses and the compiler tells me to add these typeclasses to function signatures of `catchMonadFileBasedIO` and `liftMonadFileBasedIO`. Also I would need to derive `MonadIO` from `MyDbFileBased m`. Then what's the point of replacing `IO` with a generic `Monad` in the first place?

I don't understand if I should be mocking `IO` in cases such as these or not. How do I use `liftIO` and `catch` if we mock it? Should I not catch exceptions in this module and cascade them to application level?

Comment: FYI, FP Complete suggest not to use the `ExceptT IO` pattern, for `IO` implies you can throw any exception you want, and the `ExceptT e` suggests that the action can only throw exceptions of type `e` (through `throwE`), which is a false implication.

Comment: @Krantz So should I not write generic monads (`ExceptT e m`) and simply always write specific monads (`ExceptT IOException IO`) ?

Comment: According to that article, actually, when you have IO in your monad stack, that implies all kinds of exceptions can happen through `throwIO`, so there is no point adding another layer of `ExceptT`. If you are interested, google “ReaderT design pattern”, and you will find this article.

Answer (score 2):

> Then what's the point of replacing `IO` with a generic `Monad` in the first place?

As a general piece of advice, that might enable you to replace `IO` with something pure when testing.

[Unit tests ought to be deterministic](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html), which is one of the two characteristics of [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Thus, being able to frame any problem in terms of pure functions makes it [intrinsically testable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/07/functional-design-is-intrinsically-testable).

In order to make a set of interactions pure and testable, you can, for example, replace `m` with `State`, and run your unit tests in the `State` monad. [Here's an example](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/03/11/an-example-of-state-based-testing-in-haskell). Here's [an example with `Writer`](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/08/a-pure-test-spy).

In general, I'd recommend avoiding 'mocking' if possible. In object-oriented programming, this may be a necessary evil to enable testing, but it typically leads to hard-to-maintain code. In functional programming, unit testing is much easier, but it typically requires you to design the modules of your application in a functional style.

Introducing a type class as something equivalent to an object-oriented interface or base class is unlikely to lead to a a functional design. This will pull you towards a programming model where the (impure) interactions are at the centre of your application architecture. That's exactly what makes object-oriented programming so difficult.

In functional programming, you're much better off [pushing the impure interactions to the edge of the system](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/18/functional-architecture-is-ports-and-adapters). This'll enable you to unit test your (pure) domain logic, while the IO remains concrete.